# composer install autoload failed

Tags: composer-php

On the first composer install command ( just after the clone on project ), I got this error:

```
Generating autoload files
  [ErrorException]
  Undefined index: vulnerabilities
```

With some more verbosity, I get this :

```
Generating autoload files
composer/package-versions-deprecated: Generating version class...
composer/package-versions-deprecated: ...done generating version class
Downloading https://flex.symfony.com/p/symfony,polyfill-php80,iv1.22.1,1610038173;jean85,pretty-package-versions,i1.6.0,1612455616;symfony,lock,iv4.2.12,1561965886

                                    
  [ErrorException]                  
  Undefined index: vulnerabilities  
                                    

Exception trace:
 () at /var/www/bridge-landwehr/vendor/symfony/flex/src/Downloader.php:144
 Composer\Util\ErrorHandler::handle() at /var/www/bridge-landwehr/vendor/symfony/flex/src/Downloader.php:144
 Symfony\Flex\Downloader->getRecipes() at /var/www/bridge-landwehr/vendor/symfony/flex/src/Flex.php:589
 Symfony\Flex\Flex->fetchRecipes() at /var/www/bridge-landwehr/vendor/symfony/flex/src/Flex.php:313
 Symfony\Flex\Flex->update() at /var/www/bridge-landwehr/vendor/symfony/flex/src/Flex.php:299
 Symfony\Flex\Flex->install() at n/a:n/a
 call_user_func() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/EventDispatcher/EventDispatcher.php:176
 Composer\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher->doDispatch() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/EventDispatcher/EventDispatcher.php:96
 Composer\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher->dispatchScript() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/Installer.php:324
 Composer\Installer->run() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/Command/InstallCommand.php:121
 Composer\Command\InstallCommand->execute() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php:245
 Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:835
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:185
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/Console/Application.php:258
 Composer\Console\Application->doRun() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:117
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/Console/Application.php:104
 Composer\Console\Application->run() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/bin/composer:56
 require() at /usr/local/bin/composer:24
```

It seems to be a problem with symfony/flex. Because when I check the file download : https://flex.symfony.com/p/symfony,polyfill-php80,iv1.22.1,1610038173;jean85,pretty-package-versions,i1.6.0,1612455616;symfony,lock,iv4.2.12,1561965886, where is no key "vulnerabilities"

If I re-run the composer install a second time there is no problem. Did someone know why ?

composer version in 1.8.0

Comment: Please share more details, like the code involved and your attempts to resolve the problem

Comment: I do not know what more detail gives. The error only come on fist composer install.

Comment: According to the pretty short error message, any script is throwing that error. What have you tried to check which of them? And what have you tried to resolve the problem? To me, this looks like a problem that is not related to Composer itself

Comment: Also, please share more details about the Composer version you are using. There is no version 1.18.0 yet - the latest version on the v1 branch is 1.10.18

Comment: Please share more details. The code indicates a problem in `symfony/flex` - which version did you install?

Comment: After searching further: checking for these vulnerabilities has been removed in https://github.com/symfony/flex/pull/454 more than two years ago(!) - looks like you should update your dependencies?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error suddenly for no apparent reason. I tried finding the culprit, but it started taking too long.

I fixed it by upgrading packages.

1-Try upgrading composer to from version 1 to version 2 (2.0.13 worked for me).

```
//Check your composer version 
composer -v
```

2-Make sure to fully upgrade to Symfony 4.4.* (In my case, I was in version 4.2-4.3 for some components) Follow these steps: https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/upgrade_minor.html

Symfony flex version 1.12.2 worked for me with symfony 4.4

I previously thought 4.4 would be breaking for me but it was not. My error was to previously try to upgrade to 4.3. Skip that one!

4.4 Is also supported until november 2022 unlike other minor versions in V4.