# Composer install suddenly fails because of symfony/flex

Tags: symfony, composer-php, symfony-flex

I'm having this problem out of the blue. I didn't change anything in composer and it ran just fine up until last week. Now when I run composer install I get this at the end:

```
Generating autoload files
ocramius/package-versions:  Generating version class...
ocramius/package-versions: ...done generating version class


  [ErrorException]
  Undefined index: vulnerabilities
```

This makes my deploys crash and now I can't release anything on staging or production.

I've removed packages one by one and managed to trace the issue back to symfony/flex. I tried updating it, but composer just freezes on a random step that means nothing to me.

I've tried removing it and running a clean `composer require symfony/flex` in case there was a problem with my version - it installs it then tries to update dependencies and freezes forever.

I've tried:

`composer clearcache`

`composer self-update`

`composer update --no-plugins --noscripts`

Nothing works. It still freezes on update and still gives me the error on install. I am nearing desperation.

This is my composer.json file:

```
{
  "type": "project",
  "minimum-stability": "dev",
  "prefer-stable": true,
  "require": {
    "php": "^7.1.3",
    "ext-iconv": "*",
    "ext-json": "*",
    "ext-intl": "*",
    "beberlei/doctrineextensions": "^1.2",
    "brick/math": "0.7.*",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "^1.12.6",
    "dompdf/dompdf": "^0.8.2",
    "fervo/enum-bundle": "^2.2",
    "friendsofsymfony/jsrouting-bundle": "^2.1",
    "friendsofsymfony/rest-bundle": "^2.0",
    "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "^2.1.2",
    "knplabs/knp-snappy-bundle": "^1.5",
    "lexik/jwt-authentication-bundle": "^2.6",
    "nelmio/api-doc-bundle": "^3.6",
    "phpoffice/phpword": "^0.14.0",
    "predis/predis": "^1.1",
    "sc0vu/web3.php": "dev-master",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^5.1",
    "sg/datatablesbundle": "v1.0.4",
    "simplethings/entity-audit-bundle": "^1.0",
    "snc/redis-bundle": "^2.0",
    "sonata-project/admin-bundle": "^3.49",
    "sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle": "^3.4",
    "sonata-project/easy-extends-bundle": "^2.5",
    "sonata-project/user-bundle": "^4.1",
    "symfony/asset": "^4.0",
    "symfony/console": "^4.0",
    "symfony/debug-pack": "*",
    "symfony/expression-language": "^4.0",
    "symfony/flex": "v1.1",
    "symfony/form": "^4.0",
    "symfony/framework-bundle": "^4.0",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "^3.1",
    "symfony/orm-pack": "^1.0",
    "symfony/process": "^4.0",
    "symfony/security": "^4.0",
    "symfony/security-bundle": "^4.0",
    "symfony/security-csrf": "^v4.0",
    "symfony/serializer-pack": "*",
    "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "^3.1",
    "symfony/translation": "^4.0",
    "symfony/validator": "^4.0",
    "symfony/web-link": "^4.0",
    "symfony/webpack-encore-pack": "^1.0",
    "symfony/yaml": "^4.0",
    "twilio/sdk": "^5.0",
    "web3p/ethereum-tx": "^0.3.4",
    "willdurand/js-translation-bundle": "2.6.6"
  },
  "require-dev": {
    "ext-json": "*",
    "behat/symfony2-extension": "^2.1.5",
    "doctrine/data-fixtures": "^1.3",
    "hautelook/alice-bundle": "^2.0",
    "phpmd/phpmd": "^2.6",
    "phpstan/phpstan": "^0.10.6",
    "squizlabs/php_codesniffer": "^3.3",
    "symfony/browser-kit": "^4.0",
    "symfony/css-selector": "^4.0",
    "symfony/dotenv": "^4.0",
    "symfony/maker-bundle": "^1.0",
    "symfony/phpunit-bridge": "~4.3.0",
    "symfony/profiler-pack": "*",
    "zitec/behat-extension": "dev-master@dev"
  },
  "config": {
    "preferred-install": {
      "*": "dist"
    },
    "sort-packages": true
  },
  "autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
      "App\\": "src/"
    }
  },
  "autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": {
      "App\\Tests\\": ["tests/functional", "test/unit", "tests/api"]
    }
  },
  "replace": {
    "symfony/polyfill-iconv": "*",
    "symfony/polyfill-php71": "*",
    "symfony/polyfill-php70": "*",
    "symfony/polyfill-php56": "*"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "auto-scripts": {
      "cache:clear": "symfony-cmd",
      "cache:warmup": "symfony-cmd",
      "assets:install --symlink --relative %PUBLIC_DIR%": "symfony-cmd"
    },
    "post-install-cmd": [
      "@auto-scripts"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
      "@auto-scripts"
    ]
  },
  "conflict": {
    "symfony/symfony": "*"
  },
  "extra": {
    "symfony": {
      "id": "04C3GOB2A6BKEGTJ93E6RLD8R5",
      "allow-contrib": true
    }
  }
}
```

My composer version is 1.10.22

`composer update --vvv` freezes after these lines:

```
Downloading http://repo.packagist.org/p/athletic/athletic%247c468034c468fcf26e08cb4c4e42c29c6058991f243753f391bf4be1a93476f1.json
Writing /root/.composer/cache/repo/https---repo.packagist.org/provider-athletic$athletic.json into cache
Downloading http://repo.packagist.org/p/laminas/laminas-stdlib%243063fe25485f2f11f7dcdae0d6592d8c4740bd0e4c6fbf5fac7141542cc10d34.json
Writing /root/.composer/cache/repo/https---repo.packagist.org/provider-laminas$laminas-stdlib.json into cache
Downloading http://repo.packagist.org/p/zendframework/zend-hydrator%24929a25c4d947fc57e2c18901b036ca54a167be6e1ac3b7a7ebc22757a91784a3.json
Writing /root/.composer/cache/repo/https---repo.packagist.org/provider-zendframework$zend-hydrator.json into cache
Downloading http://repo.packagist.org/p/laminas/laminas-hydrator%24a55a80ba78a25b92b6156070846ea5bcd90dfa7fc7c51c707f62695d865e56ab.json
Writing /root/.composer/cache/repo/https---repo.packagist.org/provider-laminas$laminas-hydrator.json into cache
```

Does anyone have any clue what might be causing this or what else I could try? Lots of please and many thanks!

Comment: As already commented in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67366109/composer-install-autoload-failed: that looks like code from `symfony/flex` which is more than two years old. What happens if you run `composer update symfony/flex`?

Comment: If I run composer update symfony/flex, it hangs forever after the lines I pasted above (last code block).

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Which PHP version are you using? Have you tried using Composer v2?

Comment: I'm on PHP 7.2.34 and I've tried deleting my whole vendor folder and then using symfony/flex v1.12.2 or higher. Didn't work. I tried upgrading to Composer 2 - it told me I needed to upgrade my packages because some were not compatible, and then when I tried to run the update it just went on hanging again...

Comment: @Beckeli did you ever get to the  bottom of this? I'm having the same issue, I think

Comment: @MichaelCameron Well, yes and no. I noticed that older branches seemed to work and Git identified symfony.lock as the difference, although it wasn't able to tell me what exactly was different about it. It looked virtually the same. Regardless, I copied that file from the old branch to a new one and it worked. Weird but well...

Answer (score 3):

Had same issue with `v1.1.8` of `symfony/flex` updated it to `v1.17.2` and problem was solved.

To update it just run:
`composer update symfony/flex`

Comment: Thaks for this.
After updating symfony/flex i got error in polyfill, run composer update symfony/polyfill-php80 resolved all errors